# enumerateObjectsUsingBlock ever returns any BOOL value?

Tags: ios, enumeration, objective-c-2.0

When I was searching enumerateObjectsUsingBlock on NSArray, by accident went to NSSet Class Reference which offers the same method signature... Doc says

```
Executes a given Block using each object in the set.
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, BOOL *stop))block
block: The Block to apply to elements in the set.

obj:The element in the set.

stop:A reference to a Boolean value. The block can set the value to YES to stop further processing of the set. The stop argument is an out-only argument. You should only ever set this Boolean to YES within the Block.
```

**The Block returns a Boolean value that indicates whether obj passed the test.**

Which returned Boolean is that? Since the block is declared to return void, and “stop” argument can only be set to “YES”, how could its failing test message be passed out off the block?

During my testing, I assigned this method to a BOOL, but complier warned " Initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an expression of incompatible type 'void'"

Any ideas?

Comment: Congratulations. You found a problem in Apple's documentation. If you use the online documentation, you will find a link to report the problem.

Comment: I thought there maybe something hidden in NSSet, who has no index (comparing to NSArray), has no key (comparing with NSDictionary)...this method may provide some special feature in the out-only "stop" argument specifically for this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block doesn't *return* a boolean. The block is *passed* a *reference* to a boolean. Inside the block it should be set to YES to indicate that enumeration should stop.

```
    [items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if (obj == something){
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
```

The [documentation for NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:) does not indicate that the block *returns* a boolean:

> Executes a given block using each object in the array, starting with the first object and continuing through the array to the last object.

And the block signature indicates it returns void.

`(void (^)(id obj, BOOL *stop))`

The first void: (**void** (^)(id obj, BOOL *stop)) is the return type of the block.

Answer (score 2):

It's an error in the documentation. Enumeration blocks never return anything, as you noticed in the block's signature.

Answer (score 2):

That's a mistake in the docs. There is no `BOOL` returned from the block just as the signature indicates.

That comment seems to be a copy/paste problem from a method like `objectsPassingTest:`.

There is a link at the bottom of each page in the docs to report feedback. Let Apple know of the mistake.